# How to install android studio sdk package that already downloaded in the background?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

As shown in the image package downloaded and ready to install, but how to start installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tick the checkbox (red in the picture)

[image]

And click *Apply*.